# Can't flip/mirror animation correctly

Tags: animation, mirror

I've searched over lots of threads related with this topic, but I can't
manage to flip animation correctly.
I have a armature, with one animation in-place, moving character to the right.I just want to flip/mirror animation so that it do it to the left. 
 I selected legs/foot/root bones (Don't want to change arms position) in 3d View,
and from dopesheet I copy and pasted with Control+Shift+V all keyframes, but result 
is not good. I don't know if the problem is that this method rotates on all axis
or that rotations are quaternions and can't be managed like this..
New at blender.. and with animations :(
Any help appreciated.

Attached my blender file. Until frame 80, original animation. From frame 150 starts my flipped
version.

[image]